# Read fragment content in viewpager on swipe with talkback accessibility mode

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have a viewpager that contains multiple fragments. When the activity is launched, I can read the content of fragment with a click. But when swipe, talkback only announce the pager position without reading the content. Is there a way to announce the page number then read it's content?

Answer (score -1):

You can set contentsDescription to Fragment's child view.

For example, if you have a TextView and it has contents that you want to speak by talk back, you can do this:

```
textView.setContentDescription("Hello world");
```

Or, you can add "android:contentDescription" to xml.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="Hello world"
    </TextView>
```